# VIM 8.2 Term Buffer Shortcut

Tags: vim

In my workflow, I have mapped ctr+right and Ctr+left to toggle my buffers in VIM. However, Whenever I reach to a terminal buffer, the terminal doesn't move to a next buffer. I think the key is not handed over to vim instead it is with term. How can I make certain keys to go pass the terminal so I can switch buffer without mouse? I am using windows 10 with GVIM 8.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's probably happening while your terminal is in terminal-insert mode, capturing keystrokes and sending them to the program running inside the terminal.

You can still create mappings for those keys using the `:tnoremap` command. See `:help :tnoremap` and [`:help mapmode-t`](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#mapmode-t).

For example:

```
tnoremap <C-Left> <C-w>h
tnoremap <C-Right> <C-w>l
```

(Not sure these were the actual mappings you were using in normal mode, or if you were using `<C-w>W` and `<C-w>w`. In any case, you get the idea, use `tnoremap` to replicate the mappings in terminal-insert mode as well.)

**UPDATE:** From your comment, you're switching buffers with these mappings, so these should work:

```
tnoremap <C-Left> <C-w>:bp<CR>
tnoremap <C-Right> <C-w>:bn<CR>
```

These will differ from the normal mode mappings in that they need the `<C-w>` prefix, which is needed to enter an Ex command from a terminal in terminal-insert mode.

Comment: Thanks, I usually create the terminal with term++hidden. I did these mapping by referring to the doc you posted.   (tnoremap <C-Left> <C-w>:bp<CR>   tnoremap <C-Right> <C-w>:bn<CR>)